# laravel-imap, issues with getting only text content of body

Tags: php, laravel, imap

I'm using Laravel-IMAP from webklex (version 1.6) and I'm having an issue getting consistent email bodies in just plain text with no HTML or CSS tags. It seems like a simple email from my personal address to this test address isn't an issue, as it mainly shows the text of the body with &nbsp and the signature text.

However, on a more spam-like email with a very heavily formatted HTML/CSS/JS body, this is still letting the entire CSS section by.

**My code:**

```
public function format_html_body($str) {
    $str = htmlentities($str, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
    $str = str_replace(chr(10), "<br>", $str);
    return $str;
}

//within another function
$body = $oMessage->getHTMLBody();
$stripped_body = strip_tags($body);
$formatted_body = preg_replace('/\s+|body {.*}/', ' ', $stripped_body);
$final_Content = self::format_html_body($formatted_body);
echo $final_Content;
```

An example of what I'm seeing when echoing `$final_content`:

```
email td { padding: 0px; } p { margin: 0px; } @media only screen and (max-width:768px) { .container { width:90% !important; min-width:90% !important; } .mobile-cell { display:block; width:100%; } .theme-digest { padding:0 20px !important; } .theme-pyd { height: 100%; width: 600px !important; } .sm-hidden { display:none !important; } .sm-shown { display:block !important; } .footer .left-side, .footer .right-side { width:100% !important; display:block !important; padding:10px !important; text-align:center !important; } } /* remember to define focus styles! */ .bodyDirection_ltr { direction:ltr; } .bodyDirection_rtl { direction:rtl; } .ltr { text-align:left; }
```

Comment: `strip_tags` will remove the tags and keep their content, you probably need a more sophisticated way of removing the content of `<style>` tags

Comment: @apokryfos Ok that makes sense actually. I think I went about the priorities wrong, so I'm using a regex to remove anything between style and script tags, and then after that working on removing tags and whitespace. Maybe that will be closer to what I expect